# Custom structure in a list within a wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a custom menu by using the Wordpress menu functionality.

This usually outputs a list for each element on the menu:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#whatever">Element 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#whatever">Element 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

But for my design I would like to get something like this for **each element on the list**

```
<li class="whatever">
    <div class="imageWrap">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#link_here">
            Title
        </a>
        <div class="whatever">
            <p>Title of description</p>
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

What would be the easiest way to for it?

I've been reading [this article](https://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/) which suggest to use the function `wp_get_nav_menu_items` instead. But the problem is I'm not actually using any function.
When the user decides to add a **Menu widget** in a side bar or the footer of the site, wordpress deals with it by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [Walker_Nav_Menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_custom_Walker_class) Class. Edit the HTML as needed.

Also make sure you edit the template which calls the `wp_nav_menu` function (mostly the `header.php` file) and add the `walker` parameter to it.

Comment: I'm talking about dynamic menus created in the dashboard. I have no function `wp_nav_menu ` in any of my sidebar PHP files. Wordpress displays a menu if the user adds a menu widget (or a text if its a text widget or whatever )

Comment: Well. The *Menu widget* that you're talking about uses this function within its code. To customize the HTML structure, you'll have to copy the code from that widget and create a new widget.

Comment: Check the file named `default-widgets.php` in the wp-includes folder and locate the code that creates the *Menu Widget*